# Pointer to multidimensional array C++

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am trying to understand how to use pointers with multidimensional arrays (E.g: 2 dimensions, 3 dimensions...). I saw a lot of resources online for it, but I still can't seem to understand it. The syntax is also throwing me off. What do these following syntaxes mean (Why do we need parenthesis)? What does the code do and how does it work? Thank you!

**Example 1**

```
int (*array)[5] = new int[10][5];
```

**Example 2**

```
int c[3][2][2]; 
int (*p)[2][2] = c;
```

Comment: `int *array[5];` defines `array` as an array of five pointers to `int`. `int (*array)[5];` defines `array` as a pointer to an array of five `int` values.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude is right and very succinct. You can read more on this [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_array_of_pointers.htm).

Comment: This toy tool can be of help to fiddle for distinct meanings of types with and without parentheses: [C gibberish ↔ English](https://cdecl.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `int (*arr)[5]` : `arr` is *pointer*, pointing to an array of 5 ints
2. `int (*p)[2][2] = c;`  : `p` is a *pointer*, pointing to an array of 2, with each row having an array of 2 `ints`

How does it work? Look at the following simple example:

```
    int (*array)[2] = new int[3][2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            array[i][j] = i + j;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            cout << array[i][j] << ' ';
        cout << '\n';
    }
```

Output:

```
0 1 
1 2 
2 3
```

#### Why do we need parenthesis?

Consider:

```
int *arr[3];
```

Here, `arr` is an array of size 3, which can store 3 pointers. So it is an array of pointers. See:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 20;
int c = 30;
arr[0] = &a; //arr[0] pointing to a
arr[1] = &b; //arr[1] pointing to b
arr[2] = &c; //arr[2] pointing to c
```